# Local domain access issues

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, dhcp, sonicwall

I moved our DHCP from a windows small business 2008 server to our sonicwall firewall. when I try and domain a computer to the local domain on the server I get an error."That domain couldnt be found. Check the domain name and try again." What are potential troubleshooting steps i can take? Networking is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the new DHCP scope's / pool's  DNS servers are the IP addresses of the domain controller servers.

Comment: this was the issue, changed the DHCP scopes DNS to that of the domain controller servers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing the SRV records for the Windows domain which would have been created automatically by Windows Server but would not have been added to your Sonicwall.

You'll need the bare minimum of;

```
_ldap._tcp.internal.domain.com
_kerberos._udp.internal.domain.com
server.internal.domain.com
```

which point to your Windows Domain Controller.

Comment: Alright I will take a look into this, thank you for the suggestions